# insert values into my json between tags

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have this code:

```
$json = '[{"data":{"name":"Widget Shop USA","widget_a":300,"widget_b":250},"template":{"name":"<h1 class=\"name\"></h1>","cost":"<span class=\"cost\">Price: $</span>"}}]';

$array = json_decode($json, true);

$widget_a = $array[0]['data']['widget_a'];
$widget_b = $array[0]['data']['widget_b'];
$data_name = $array[0]['data']['name'];

$array[0]['template']['cost'] .= $widget_a + $widget_b;

$array[0]['template']['name'] .= $data_name;
```

What i am trying to do is to get the `$array[0]['template']['cost']` and the `$array[0]['template']['name']` and pass them into `$json` variable between the HTML fragments (h1,span). How can i achieve that?

i try to encode the `$array`:

```
$json_new = json_encode($array);
```

but the variables comes after the HTML fragments...Is there any way to pass it between H1 and SPAN tags?

Comment: where did you get the json from? it is not a valid JSON object: using a validator to check: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Let's say that i have this json: {
 "employees": [{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe"
 }],
 "name": "<h2></h2>"

}   How can i pass the firstName into the h2 tags..??

Comment: I want to say..lets say that we have a correct json file..whats the way to do what i want?

Comment: does that answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

To the question addressed in you comment, you can loop through a JSON, grab the relevant property and assign it like so:

```
function mm(obj) {
 for (var prop in obj) {
   obj.name = "<h2>" +  obj.employees[0].firstName +"</h2>";
 }
  return obj;
}

console.log(mm(json));
```

Working JSBin https://jsbin.com/sefohu/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
indexOf   and   slice

for example:

```
        $widget = $array[0].data.widget_a + $array[0].data.widget_b;
        $data_name = $array[0].data.name;


        $indexCost = $array[0].template.cost.indexOf('$<');
        $array[0].template.cost = $array[0].template.cost.slice(0, $indexCost + 1) + $widget + $array[0].template.cost.slice($indexCost + 1, $array[0].template.cost.length);


        $indexName = $array[0].template.name.indexOf('><');
        $array[0].template.name = $array[0].template.name.slice(0, $indexName + 1) + $data_name + $array[0].template.name.slice($indexName + 1, $array[0].template.name.length);


        alert($array[0].template.name);
        alert($array[0].template.cost);
```

or use temp method:

```
    $temp = document.createElement('template');
    $temp.innerHTML = $array[0]['template']['name'];
    $temp.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHTML = $array[0]['data']['name'];
    $array[0]['template']['name'] = $temp.innerHTML;
```

if you can change the json my suggestion:

```
$json = '[{"data":{"name":"Widget Shop USA","widget_a":300,"widget_b":250},"template":{"nametag":"h1","nameclass":"name","costtag":"span","costclass":"cost"}}]';
```

and use:

```
        $array = JSON.parse($json);

        $widget = $array[0].data.widget_a + $array[0].data.widget_b;

        $array[0].template.cost = '<' + $array[0].template.costtag + ' class="' + $array[0].template.costclass + '" >' + $widget + '</' + $array[0].template.costtag + '>';

        $array[0].template.name = '<' + $array[0].template.nametag + ' class="' + $array[0].template.nameclass + '" >' + $array[0].template.name + '</' + $array[0].template.nametag + '>';


        alert($array[0].template.name);
        alert($array[0].template.cost);
```